# Sed - apagar texto de uma posição até o inicio do arquivo

Tags: sed

Tenho este comando que apaga de uma posição até o final do arquivo, mas como apagar desta posição para o início do arquivo?

```
sed -i '/Enviar mailBlogThis/,$d' *.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar `sed -i '1,/destino/d' *.txt`

**Explicação:**

```
sed -i '1,/Enviar mailBlogThis/d' arquivo.txt
    └┬┘└┬┘ └────────┬────────┘└┬┘ └────┬────┘
     │  │           │          │       └─ Arquivo(s)
     │  │           │          └───────── Deleta as linhas encontradas via RegEx
     │  │           └──────────────────── Limite para remoção
     │  └──────────────────────────────── Começa deletar da primeira linhas
     └─────────────────────────────────── Altera o arquivo
```

**arquivo.txt**

```
1
2
3
4
5
Enviar mailBlogThis
6
7
8
9
0
```

**Saída:**

```
6
7
8
9
0
```

Comment: Ocorreu um problema, se no arquivo não tiver o termo (destino) ele apaga tudo do arquivo

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `grep`, por exemplo: `grep "Enviar mailBlogThis" file.txt && sed -i '1,/Enviar mailBlogThis/d' file.txt`

Comment: Agora funcionou perfeitamente, Obrigado @Valdeir